# htaccess redirect hostname to FQDN

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a machine that is local and if you type in http://host it goes to the website on it. I want to use an htaccess to redirect to http://host.domain.com. In the end it is the same I just want to use the proper url for documentation purposes. I tried this but didn't work

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
   rewritecond %{http_host} ^host [nc]
   rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://host.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`NE` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to keep characters like `?` in their raw form instead of turning them into %-escapes, losing their special meaning.

However `mod_rewrite` is a clumsy way of doing a simple redirect. If you can get access to the main/virtual host config you are better off using `Redirect`, the tool that was designed for this job:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName host.domain.com
    ... real host settings...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName host
    Redirect permanent / http://host.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a negative match on the FQDN -so that anything that does not host.domain.com will be redirected to have that.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} "!^host.domain.com" [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://host.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: You dont have escaped dots in your expression.